# How to use async/await on event handlers on buttons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, async.js

I'm new too JavaScript and am having trouble with async. I have a webpage with two buttons, If the yes button is pressed it will do some code and if the no button is pressed it will do different code but regardless of which one is pressed it will continue on in the function. For Example

```
function mainloop(){

        document.getElementById("buttonyes").addEventListener("click", () => {
            /* do some code */
        })
        
        document.getElementById("buttonno").addEventListener("click", () => {
            /* do some different code */
        })
        /* wait for either button to be pressed and then continue with code */
        console.log("yay waiting for stuff")
}
```

I believe the solution to this is promises and creating other functions to handle the buttons; however, tutorials I've seen only show one function solutions and if I understand correctly the EventListener when activated is using another function all to itself. I've come over from C and all this object properties asynchronization stuff is throwing me for a loop.

I'd really love a way to keep it all in the same main function as this challenge specifically called for me to use async/await on this damned buttons.

Comment: Put the `console.log` in a seperate function than call it at the end of both the first and last event handler

Comment: Is `mainloop()` called multiple times? Can the user press these buttons only once, or many times?

Comment: @Bergi currently they can be pressed multiple times (they aren't meant to be able too)... One crisis at a time though. The whole mainloop is meant to be just that a loop. A button is pressed, information is displayed and then at the end of the loop everything resets.

Comment: @TheCourtJester What do you mean by "resets"? This sounds like a problem that can't be solved just one step at a time, since it affects the whole architecture of the application.

Comment: Please be aware that `addEventListener` will remain active once you set it. If you want to make the buttons "unclickable" you could `disable` them with CSS, or you could remove the listener with `removeEventListener`, or you could keep track of the state with a variable. For example, `textDisplayed = true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **Event Handler** is already a way of using asynchronous code. The code inside the handler **already** waits to be executed until somebody presses the button.

If you have some function that needs to be executed after both clicks you can simply add it to both event handlers. Btw you don't need to put the `addEventListener` in a loop! Just add them once.

```
    document.getElementById("buttonyes").addEventListener("click", () => {
        /* do some code */
      
        myNewFunction()
    })
    
    document.getElementById("buttonno").addEventListener("click", () => {
        /* do some different code */

        myNewFunction()
    })


    /* wait for either button to be pressed and then continue with code */
    function myNewFunction() {
         console.log("yay waiting for stuff")
    }
```

You only need another `async await` if the code in the buttons does something that **needs** to be awaited, for example fetching data from the internet. Or else we need a bit more context to know why you want to solve this problem with an extra `async await`.

Answer (score -3):

I would advise you to use the async await with promise to handle this kind of scenario. eventHandler supports the async await under the hood.

Please check this example:-

```
document.querySelector('#btn')
  .addEventListener('click', handleClick)

async function handleClick() {
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
                    setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
  alert('clicked')
}
```